# Take a common out of the bitwise 'OR' operation

Tags: bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

If we have an operation (**x*A | x*B**) where '**|**' is the '**OR**' operator then what would be required to take the **x** out of the operation and get multiplied by the outcome of the left.

e.g., Let **P = (x*A | x*B)**

Then somehow, **P = x * (some expression here)**

Please let me know if this is possible and what would be the expression.

Comment: Are A and B arbitrary integers, or basically Booleans taking only the values 0 or 1?

Comment: Well this multiplication deal seems weird, but if you meant bitwise AND and then yes `(x & A) | (x & B) = x & (A | B)`

Comment: @njuffa A and B can be arbitrary integers values. Does that kind of expression seems possible? Even in case of Booleans, what can be the possible solution? Perhaps we can extend that way to deal with arbitrary integers too.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I'll assume 32bit integers (it's more general actually, but it doesn't work for ℤ).

It's possible, but this is not an optimization. Consider the case that `x` is odd:

`x` has a modular multiplicative inverse, let's call it `inv(x)`. Now plug into the template
`P = x * Expr`, `Expr = inv(x) * (x * A | x * B)`

The resulting expression is `x * inv(x) * (x * A | x * B) = x * A | x * B`.

Consider the case that `x` is even. Observe that multiplying `x` by 2 makes `x * A | x * B` twice as big too, even though a nonlinear "OR" operation is involved, because multiplying by two is just a left shift and left shift distributes over OR.

Factor `x` into `y * d` where `y` is odd and `d` is a power of two. Now let the "evenness" come from the final multiplication by `x`, and write `Expr = inv(y) * (y * A | y * B)`.

Plugging that back into the template we get `y * d * inv(y) * (y * A | y * B)`, which simplifies to `d * (y * A | y * B)`, which is `x * A | x * B` again.

This case is actually the general case, because `d` can be set equal to 1 for odd `x`.